# как создать такую переменну, которая будет хранить данные из $_SESSION[id] и не будет изменяться?

Tags: php

как создать такую переменну, которая будет хранить данные из $_SESSION[id] и не будет изменяться?Тоесть, есть у меня переменная $id в которой хранится $_SESSION[id] и он равен = 1.Если я перезайду на страницу с аккаунтом, у которого id 50 то и $id будет равен 50, но мне надо, чтобы значение $id не изменялось и всегда было равно 1.(константы не работают)

Answer (score 2):

Переменные на то и переменные. Нужно хранить либо в бд, либо в файлах, либо в куках, либо в отдельной сессии вообще.
лучше конечно в бд, зависит от задачи.